# Is there a public beta for Steam for Linux?

Tags: steam

Its hard to follow up with all the news since all the websites say their own thing. I'm wondering is there is a beta or at least an alpha for Steam for Linux. I saw on youtube how someone starts 2.2 beta, but it seems all the download links are broken. Can someone explain the situation please? Is it because Valve just doesn't want anyone using the program yet?

Comment: On a side note, Steam Linux officially launched last week and this question should probably be closed as Too Localized.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Steam Beta is ONLINE!

[Wiki on Installing Steam on Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve#Installing_Valve_Steam_Beta_on_Ubuntu_12.04)

[Steam Download for Linux](http://store.steampowered.com/about/) (Updated)

---

[Phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTIyMzA)

[Valve Blog (How the Beta will work)](http://blogs.valvesoftware.com/linux/)

[Steam Blog with Announcement](http://store.steampowered.com/news/9289/)

[Official Steam Linux Site](http://steamcommunity.com/linux)

[Steam Beta DEB Package](http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb)

Note - It will not work if you are not registered in Steam (Non-Steam users beware!)

Comment: yeah, You guys are lucky. We ,ati users, suffer alot (black screen) when using steam.

Comment: which amd card do you have? i got the Radeon HD 4850

Comment: Luis Alvarado, do you mind sending me an e-mail everytime news come up? thanks :)

Comment: Find in me Google+ and I will post news about it friend.

Comment: Beta Steam can be found here http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb

Comment: How do you get Flash Player working? And does anyone have a packed version of TF2 that they want to share? I'm not in the beta (yet).

Comment: Flash player is with the ubuntu-restricted-extras package.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Luis Alvarado answer:

A workaround exists to use Steam without beta access.

```
steam steam://open/friends
```

Steams friend list will open. Via this menu you can open the main window of Steam.

Comment: works, but none of the games launch including serious sam, left 4 dead 2 and team fortress 1 or 2. i've got them all

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to bump an old question, but the **public** Beta started yesterday (2012/12/20) as opposed to the private Beta that was going on prior to this week.

Either add the [Steam Repo](http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/) to your apt-sources and run `sudo apt-get install steam_latest` or [download the .deb manually](http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb) and install it using dpkg.

Oh, and make sure you [report any issues](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues) you run into on their [GitHub](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux) page.  You may also want to join Valve's [steamrepo mailing list](https://list.valvesoftware.com/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/steamrepo) so you get updates as to when Steam needs to be updated.